# Printing contents of String Vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

Ok,  I've almost got this working but I'm stuck with the second part of b., getting it to display the words in that position in the array. Here is the list of what I need it to do.

1. Read 50 words from a text file into an array of strings
2. The program will use random numbers for:

   a.-  It will generate a random number between 2 and 7 for the selection of the words to be used in the sentence

   b.- It will generate a random number for the selection of the words.  The number will be between 0 and 49, because those are the  positions of the words in the array
3. It will  display the sentence on the screen.

Thank you ahead of time for any suggestions

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream outFile;
    ifstream inFile;
    string word;
    vector <string> words;
    srand(time(0));

    int Random2 = rand() % 7 + 1;
    inFile.open("words.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open()) { //tests to see if file opened corrected
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (getline(inFile, word)) { //Puts file info into string
        words.push_back(word);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Random2; i++) {
        int Random1 = rand() % 49 + 1;
        cout << words[Random1] << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand it. Is the first random number the number of words in the sentence?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 1) Develop new functionality *in isolation*. 2) Good indentation is like good grooming. 3) An array and a vector are not the same thing. 4) "The words in that position in the array" doesn't make much sense. 5) Be sure you understand `getline` before you use it. 6) You're drawing a random number from [1,...,50].

Comment: What is your actual problem? The code you have looks OK apart from you are choosing random words from 1 to 49 instead of 0 to 49.

Comment: Yes, the first random number is the number of words in the sentence. The actual problem I'm having is having it print the words to console from the vector. Sorry if I might have some ideas or words confused, I'm quite new to C++ and some parts have been causing me to struggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic to generate the random numbers in the expected range is not correct.

```
int Random2 = rand() % 7 + 1;
```

That puts the range of `Random2` to 1 to 7, both inclusive. If you want the range to be 2 o 7, both inclusive, you need to use:

```
int Random2 = rand() % 6 + 2;
```

And ...

```
int Random1 = rand() % 49 + 1;
```

That puts the range or `Random1` to 1 to 49, both inclusive. If you want the range to be 0 to 49, both inclusive, you need to use:

```
int Random1 = rand() % 50;
```

Rest of your code looks OK to me.

Comment: When I run it, I'm getting a error that says, " Debug Assertion Failed!, Expression "Standard C++ Libraries Out of Range" &&0. I"m using Microsoft VIsual Studio to build and compile everything.

Comment: That would be the case if there are less than 50 items in `words`. To account for that, use `size_t size = words.size();` and `int Random1 = rand()%size;`.